# How to refer to column inside gsub when using mutate_at(vars(contains(...))

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to remove all spaces from columns where I know the column names contain a specific string

Reproducible example

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x_first = c("How are you", "Hello", "Good bye"), x_second = c(1:3))

      x_first x_second
1 How are you        1
2       Hello        2
3    Good bye        3

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(contains("first")), gsub(" ", "", vars(.))
```

But I can't find out how I'm supposed to refer to the column inside `gsub`, right now I have `vars(.)` but this gives an error.

I would like to get

```
    x_first x_second
1 Howareyou        1
2     Hello        2
3   Goodbye        3
```

Comment: You can do `df %>%
 mutate(across(contains("first"), ~ gsub(" ", "", .)))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lastest version of `dplyr` prefers to use the new `across()` function rather than `mutate_at`. Here's what that would look like

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(contains("first"), ~gsub(" ", "", .)))
```

You can use `~` to create an anonymous function where `.` will be the data from that column.

But the same would work for `mutate_at`

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(contains("first")), ~gsub(" ", "", .))
```

or you can use the longer function syntax

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(contains("first")), function(x) gsub(" ", "", x))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `str_remove` from `stringr`.  It may be better to use a regex pattern `\\s+` - i.e. one or more space so that if there is any chance of having unequal width of spaces, it gets removed

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
      mutate(across(ends_with('first'), str_remove_all, "\\s+"))
```

-output

```
#     x_first x_second
#1 Howareyou        1
#2     Hello        2
#3   Goodbye        3
```